# How to search and print corresponding value of match from the command line?

Tags: command-line, awk, sed

I have below string,
e.g.

```
2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - MATCH: 10 [text]
```

I want to find `MATCH` and print its value, 10, using `awk`. I am able to do this using traditional `grep` and `cut` but want to find way using `sed` or `awk`.

`MATCH` can be at any position on the line.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed -n 's/.* MATCH: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Would print the sequence of non-space characters that follow the right-most occurrence of `" MATCH: "` on every matching line.

`-n` tells `sed` not to print the pattern space by default. And the `p` flag to the `s` command tells `sed` to print the pattern space (so the result of the substitution) if the substitution is successful.

So the:

```
sed -n 's/pattern/replacement/p'
```

is a common idiom to print the result of successful substitutions.

Note that the above assumes the input is valid text. Since `.*` matches any sequence of *characters*, it won't match on sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters. That typically happens in UTF-8 locales when processing text in another encoding. If you're in such a case, you may want to prefix that line above with `LC_ALL=C`. That makes `sed` treat each byte as a character so there's no possible invalid byte sequence. That would work here as the characters we're matching on are all from the portable character  set.

Standard `awk` doesn't have anything equivalent as it doesn't support capture groups (the `\(...\)` captured in `\1`) in it's `sub()` function.

There, you need to resort to the `match()` function:

```
awk 'match($0, / MATCH: [^ ]*/) {
       print substr($0, RSTART+8, RLENGTH-8)}'
```

Or use tricks like:

```
awk -F ' MATCH: ' 'NF>1 {sub(/ .*/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

(beware that those would consider the *leftmost* occurrence of `" MATCH: "`).

GNU `awk` has a `gensub()` function that has functionality similar to `sed`'s `s` command, but a design mistake in that it doesn't tell you whether any substitution was done. Here, you could do:

```
 gawk '(replacement = gensub(/.* MATCH: ([^ ]*).*/, "\\1", 1)) != $0 {
   print replacement}'
```

Comment: Getting some different results using this way

Answer (score 2):

Given the assumption that all your lines are formated the same (or at least all the lines containing `MATCH:`), it appears that `MATCH:` is the 5th element of the line, and the value you want is the 6th one.

Therefore in awk you just have to test if the 5th element is equal to `MATCH:` and print the 6th element of the line if correct.

```
$ echo "2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - MATCH: 10 [text]" |awk -e '{ if ($5 == "MATCH:") print $6 }' 
    10
```

EDIT: Given the assumption `MATCH:` can be anywhere in the line:

```
  $ echo "2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - MATCH: 10 [text]" |awk -e '{ for (x=1; x<NF; x++ ) { if ($x == "MATCH:") {x=x+1; printf("%s\n", $x); break}}}' 
10
```

Might not be very elegant, but you need to iter through all fields of the line and test each field, which is done with a `for` loop, and an `if` test. 
If test field is matching, then print the next field.

I just added a break to directly jump to the next line and and continue the current field iteration.

On a multi line file:

```
$ cat terst 
2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - MATCH: 10 [text]
2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - MATCH: 11 [text]
2017-01-19:31:51 [ABCD:] 37723 - [text]
2017-01-19:31:51 37723 - MATCH: 12 [text]
$ awk -e '{ for (x=1; x<NF; x++ ) { if ($x == "MATCH:") {x=x+1; printf("%s\n", $x); break}}}' terst 
10
11
12
```

Comment: Just to add MATCH: can be at any position so more generic approach like search string and print value?

Comment: Please edit your original post, to add this information. Might not be so obvious with the current text.